# Kml mime type export

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml

I was wondering if Arcgis could export a real mime type KML file and if not how to do it. I have tried converting a layer into kml however it apparently creates a kmz which I then open in Google Earth and the saved it as a KML

Answer (score 1):

Not in ArcGIS but maybe more convenient than opening in and saving from Google Earth. You can change the file extension of the KMZ to .zip. If you extract the zip file you will get the KML.